# JavaFX combobox selected item type changes when not focused

Tags: combobox, javafx

I've encountered something I suspect is a bug in JavaFX, but I'm not entirely sure.

I've implemented a combobox using a custom data type:

```
@FXML
ComboBox <MyDataType> cbox;
```

If  I access the combobox's selected item property using:

```
MyDataType data = cbox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

it will return a reference to the selected object, but ***only if the combobox has focus***.

If the combobox does not have focus, the selected item is returned as a String and Java throws a runtime error claiming I'm trying to cast a String to MyDataType.

The exact same behavior is observed if I forgo the call to the selection model and just use:

```
MyDataType data = cbox.getValue();
```

I can solve it by simply having the combo box request focus before I retrieve the selected item, but it seems odd that I should have to do that.

I can't find any documentation on this.  Seems unlikely something this big would be a bug, but I thought I'd see if anyone knew something about it...

update:

My use case has nested one FXML component inside another, and the attempt to access the combobox's custom data value comes from a callback that's assigned to the encompassing component (it's a dialog frame with apply / done / cancel buttons that takes a separate component to provide the dialog's content).

It seems to me the issue lies here, as I've not been able to reproduce the problem in a skeleton application that uses only a single component.

Comment: You need to provide an observable example code. And also your environment.

Comment: You may update your question with recent findings you have. It may be a major bug for nested fxml usage scenario.

Comment: I've tested the issue in a skeleton application and it works perfectly, regardless of the control's focus state.

My use case is a bit more complicated (see update).  And now it seems as though I can't get at the custom data at all, even when I give the control focus.  

If I can reproduce the issue separately, I will be sure to provide an update.